# Stackapps.com API URLs not rendered as links

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, stackapps

I was putting together a [question on stackapps (quickly answered)](https://stackapps.com/questions/2930/how-do-i-get-a-filter-to-let-through-the-fields-i-specify) asking about the new API filters. I wanted to link to some relevant API docs pages with the filters already specified, but it refused to recognize the URL in the markdown.

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#filter=!6ot9yf2tHd-0A(WH5pXrL9xuH_(.UL3EF-uBGL&run=true
```

Attempted as markdown: [some url](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#filter=!6ot9yf2tHd-0A(WH5pXrL9xuH_(.UL3EF-uBGL&run=true)

I don't deny the filter ID makes these URLs very ugly, so maybe it isn't supposed to work with exclamation points and parentheses. I simply ran the URLs through a shortener to fix the issue.

Comment: You've got a couple of open parentheses there in the URL that are unencoded. They're hosing the Markdown.

Answer (score 2):

That link isn't correctly encoded.  If you use the link button in the editor toolbar, any url entered there will be encoded.

Comment: It looks like the editor is doing an equivalent of JavaScript's `encodeURIComponent`, but that doesn't alter the characters of the filter at all. I'm curious if those characters only require encoding to markdown and not for overall URI requirements.

Answer (score 1):

In Markdown, you must "backslash escape" parenthesis within such embedded components as a link. This code will work as expected (I have indicated the backslashes with carats):

```
[some url](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#filter=!6ot9yf2tHd-0A\(WH5pXrL9xuH_\(.UL3EF-uBGL&run=true)
                                                                        ^             ^
```

Example of it working: [some url](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#filter=!6ot9yf2tHd-0A(WH5pXrL9xuH_(.UL3EF-uBGL&run=true)